# Настройка поиска по связанным полям

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

Настраиваю поиск в гридвью, столкнулась с банальной проблемой. В выводимой таблице на поля из связанных таблиц не добавляется поиск. Перепробовала множество найденных примеров и гайдов, не помогло.

Модель Specialist со связями User и Organization:

```
    class Specialist extends Specialists
{
    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserModel::class, ['id' => 'id_user']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getOrganization()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Organization::class, ['id' => 'id_organization']);
    }
}
```

Модель поиска:

```
class SpecSearch extends Specialist
{
    public $userLogin;
    public $organizationShortName;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['fullname', 'organizationShortName', 'reg_date', 'userLogin'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function scenarios()
    {
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * @param $params
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Specialist::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $dataProvider->setSort(
        [
            'attributes' => ['id', 'fullname', 'userLogin']
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            $query->joinWith(['organization', 'user'], true);
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere(
        [
            'id' => $this->id,
        ]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fullname', $this->fullname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.login', $this->userLogin])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'organization.short_name', $this->organizationShortName])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'reg_date', $this->reg_date]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }

}
```

Контроллер:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new SpecSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->get());

    return $this->render('index',
        [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        ]);
}
```

Вьюха:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' =>
```

Comment: Я бы еще посмотрел на колонки в гридвью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самостоятельно разобралась, достаточно было в описании колонки сделать так:

```
'label' => 'Организация',
'attribute' => 'short_name',
'value' => 'organization.short_name',
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы осуществлялся поиск по полям связанной таблицы, необходимо присоединять эту таблицу к основной. Это делается с помощью `$query->joinWith(['organization', 'user'], true);`, но в данном случае джойн происходит только в случае, если не получилось загрузить данные в модель или не прошла валидация. Правильно будет добавить эту конструкцию перед вторым return.